# Let $r$, $s$, and $t$ be the roots of the equation $x^3 - 2x + 1 = 0$ in some order. What is the maximal value of $r^3 - s- t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, roots, maxima-minima

Let $r$, $s$, and $t$ be the roots of the equation $x^3 - 2x + 1 = 0$ in some order. What is the maximal value of $r^3 - s- t$?

How should I approach this problem?  I have no idea how to start, any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can start by finding the roots of that polynomial. Hint: $1$ is a root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for any or the three roots.

$r^3 - 2r + 1 = 0\\
r^3 = 2r - 1$

substitute:
$2r - s - t - 1$

$r + s + t = 0$ from Vieta.

Substitute again

$3r - 1$

What is the largest of the 3 roots?

Comment: $1$ is the largest root, and I got $2$ as the answer.  Is it correct?

Comment: Getting the answer is the easy part.  More importantly, do follow where the two equations I provided come from?  I didn't give you a whole lot of context there.